# The terminal shows me nothing gives unlimited space to write when i use grep function with file name in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I used this command line to see what is inside grep command but it gives unlimited space to write. Why is this happening `grep file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

It is finding instances of the literal text `file.txt` from standard input, aka your keyboard input.

If you want to search a file, use `grep PATTERN -f FILE`

Check out the [grep `man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for more details.

Plus, the entire point of grep is to search for a pattern, so you'll need that too.